# When will scrolling finally get priority?

Tags: codenameone

The Codename One tensile scrolling is a lot worse than the native scrolling in IOS. It does not feel right - not anywhere like the IOS "rubberband" effect.

And it is buggy, too. And apparently those bugs don't get priority over the years.

I feel it is high time to fix this - do You agree?

See [#2121 Native Scrolling Container](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2121)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source, feel free to submit a pull request: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/

I'm suggesting this because in one of your latest issues it was clear you don't understand the mechanics involved. Explaining why your request doesn't make sense will be the equivalent of showing you the entire source code of Codename One so consider that as an explanation...

The issues you filed in the issue tracker don't help. They are complaints not issues as only some have test cases and in those cases they refer to things that aren't as common e.g.: X scrolling with snap to grid.

About priorities that's simple. We work for the people who pay our salaries: the enterprise account users. None of them complained about the current state of the tensile drag. We have limited time and resources and we have a lot of issues/requirements and priorities. If it bothers you, fix it.

Comment: It is difficult enough to successfully market an app, especially if it doesn't have a high-quality look and feel. 
The Codename One concept convinced me. But the main incentive to use Codename One is to save effort compared to other solutions.
I can therefore only contribute to a limited extent to Codename One before it becomes unprofitable and therefore restrict myself to push you with the nose on the problem.

Comment: Did you hire a professional designer to work on the look of the app? I've worked with a lot of developers who fixate on issues like yours which do matter to a small percentage of users. However, the vast majority of users expect the app to be refined visually and if yours isn't then you will get a low rating regardless of everything else.

Comment: If my app is not up to my standards, how could it be good enough for my users - that is what I ask myself?

Comment: Standards are subjective. I have no idea what you did in your apps but from the sound of some of your issue descriptions you are trying things that won't work well in native either like overlaying text and action buttons.